# jQuery $.ajax method fails with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create simple app for displaying data from MySQL database with PHP and jQuery. But I stuck at getting the data by jQuery. My PHP script returns the data and there was no problem. I dont recive any data in the console(from `console.log(datajson);` )

Please help... I cant find any working solution. I was searching in google for at least 3-4 hours. :/

My PHP script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "pasword";
$dbname     = "dbname";

//Open connection to MySQL DataBase
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));

//Fetch table rows from MySQL DataBase
$sql = "SELECT * FROM /table-name/";
$dbresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting: " . mysqli_error($conn));

//Create an array
$dataarray[] = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) {
    $dataarray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($dataarray);

//Close the DataBase connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

JS Code:

```
var datajson = (function() {
var json = null;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    global: false,
    url: "http://kynchev.eu/database/db.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
      json = data;
      console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  });
return json;
})();
console.log(datajson);
```

The working link for the php is http://kynchev.eu/database/db.php

And example of the code at JSBin -> http://jsbin.com/nufevamulo/1/edit?js

Comment: could you please add your js code also. thanks.

Comment: *"jQuery $.ajax method fails"* Why does it fail?

Comment: Fails beause the data from the ajax request is null

Comment: Firstly, ajax should be asynchronous, and the URL, is that the same domain as your page ?

Comment: No, it is cross-domain ajax request

Comment: I have tried both true/false for async => the same result

Comment: You're not returning JSONP, but regular JSON, that's the issue. JSONP is enclosed in a function

Comment: The first problem I see is in your success callback of `$.ajax`. The first "a" in "ajax" means asynchronous and that means doing `json = data;` will happen after you `return json;` so `datajson` will always be `null`

Comment: When I try to recieve JSON it says that       XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://kynchev.eu/database/db.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8001' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: jsonp cannot be synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return valid JSONP

```
echo 'callback(' . json_encode($dataarray) . ')';
```

Then change the ajax function to

```
$.ajax({
    url           : "http://kynchev.eu/database/db.php",
    dataType      : "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback : 'callback'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

as cross-domain JSONP requests can't be synchronous

Comment: Tanks! Now i have JSONP from my PHP but the jquery - it cant reach  console.log(data);

Comment: Thanks! It's done.  I found two errors in your script code. The first one is `).done` -> `}).done` and the second `jsonp` -> `jsonpCallback`

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript expects JSONP:

> ```
> dataType: "jsonp",
> ```

but your PHP is sending JSON:

> ```
> header('Content-Type: application/json');
> echo json_encode($dataarray);
> ```

JSON is not JSONP, so it errors.

Either tell the JavaScript to expect JSON or rewrite the server side code to output JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see are:

1. If you are working from `localhost` and trying to access a remote host (eg `http://kynchev.eu/database/db.php`)  you would need something like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` but this is really unsafe because the asterisk `*` is a wildcard and could come from any remote host. I would suggest only putting trusted domains for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
2. You are trying to use `ajax` synchronously. Which is *sort of* possible with [deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/). The way you have it now, `return json;` will always return `null` because the `success` callback of the `$.ajax` method will not run before the function reaches `return json;`